# How to automatically create not exist fields by ngModel

Tags: angularjs, angular, migration

I migrate from AngularJS and counter that if I pass not exist property to `ngModel` it produces error: *Cannot read property 'stats' of undefined*

```
<input [(ngModel)]="data.main.stats.wealth" />
```

The cause of it that only `data` is defined in the constructor:

```
constructor() {
    this.data = {}
}
```

By the way, AngularJS was intelligent and automatically reconstruct all path. It even described in the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel):

> `ngModel` will try to bind to the property given by evaluating the
>   expression on the current scope. If the property doesn't already exist
>   on this scope, it will be created implicitly and added to the scope.

It breaks so much code now. I can't set elvis operators everywhere...

Comment: use proper initialization objects. Elvis operators on ngModel sound like a bad idea...

Comment: BTW, you can use `<input *ngIf="data?.main?.stats?.wealth" [(ngModel]="...">`

Comment: You get also try lodash.get method to safely access object properties

https://lodash.com/docs/#get

Comment: @Eliseo, it's too ugly.

Comment: @galvan, the problem that ngModel will not create implicitly the needed path in this case.

Comment: lodash handles this, you can use it in the following way: _.get(data, 'main.stats.wealth', defaultValue) - so if data is null or any other part of the path doesn't exist the default value returns (default value is optional)

Comment: @capolojo it may sound silly but you could wrap your input with let's say div and add *ngIf="data.main" this way angular will not create or bind the input until getting initialized.

it should look like this: 
<div *ngIf="data.main">
<input [(ngModel)]="data.main.stats.wealth" />
</div>